# Encrypting data with two separate keys

Tags: encryption, aes

### Goal

We want to find the most secure way to encrypt message of arbitrary length `M` with AES such that the recipient can only decrypt if they have both AES keys `K1` and `K2`.

### Preconditions:

- AES keys `K1` and `K2` are *independent and randomly generated*, 256-bit keys
- Assume we'll be running AES-GCM
- Key exchange for the valid recipient has already be performed
- Performance is not a concern (operation is performed less than once a couple of seconds)

### Options (I could think of)

#### Option 1: XOR

Derive a new key `K3 = K1 ^ K2` and perform encryption on `M` using `K3`.

Given that there are no known weak keys or known weaknesses in AES, only practical way for deriving `K3` is by having pre-existing knowledge of `K1` and `K2`.

#### Option 2: KDF

Compute $K_1\mathbin\|K_2$ (concatenation of the two keys) and feed the result to a KDF (perhaps HMAC based KDF) and use the resulting key as the AES key to encrypt `M`. I don't think this is significantly different from **Option 1**, but I'm listing it as an option anyway.

#### Option 3: Encrypt twice

Perform two layers of encryption:

```
C1 = Encrypt(M, K1)
C2 = Encrypt(C1, K2)
```

Send `C2` as the cipher text. My intuition is that this should be no less secure than *Option 1*.

### Additional Information/Clarifications

This question is gear towards the two keys being used as something similar to the cryptographic equivalent of "Multi-factor Authentication". In particular, the user has to obtain two different keys (through different means) before being able to decrypt the data.

This question could be extended to the case where there are `N` keys. The constraint is that all `N` keys will always be required to decrypt the data.

Comment: Secret sharing?

Comment: @kelalaka: the easiest way to do $(2, 2)$ secret sharing is his option 1.  Now, if the requirement was to have 3 keys, and you need any 2 to decrypt, well, secret sharing is the obvious method...

Comment: Secret sharing is definitely an option but seems overkill. When my scenario scales to `N` keys, all `N` keys will *always be required*. I'll add the scaling part to the body of the question.

Comment: Secret Sharing scales very well, the crucial part is the dealer, and when the secret is constructed. But why the message requires multiple keys to decrypt?

Comment: You mean `K1 + K2` or `K1||K2`  or `K1 ∥ K2` or better $K_1\mathbin\|K_2$ (written `$K_1\mathbin\|K_2$`) where there is `K1 + K1`. Is "AES" the block cipher (in which case `M` is restricted to 16 bytes), or some AES-based encryption (and then is that specified)? What's the key size (128, 192 or 256 bits)?

Comment: The idea is to require multiple keys to decrypt the data in a way similar to multi-factor authentication: the user has to obtain multiple keys through different channels. For example, one key might be a key stored in the user's iCloud keychain, while another is on a USB/device that's physically locked/guarded by another party

Comment: yes @fgrieu Thanks for pointing that out. I've added some additional assumptions (`M` being an arbitrary message, and we are going to be using AES under GCM mode)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that all of them are valid options, with the security differences they might have negligible. So I focused on other properties of the approaches:

**Option 1: XOR**

I think the most interesting property here is the malleability that gives us the XOR function. If I'm a keyholder under this chema, I could give n keys which XOR to my half to my n children, and their keys combined will be as good as mine.

Similarly, it the requisites went from 2-people to 3-people (such as including a new partner in the business), they could each provide a random half-key to combine with their now-new-half.

It also has the property of being commutative. This is silly from a cryptographic and technological point of view, but if you are giving two keys to two people, one might think to be more important to have the "first" key, or feel hurted on their big ego for only being given the "second" key. Here, both keys are equal rank, their order doesn't matter at all.

**Option 2: KDF**

This woud be similar to the above, but not allowing you such malleability (which you may consider good or bad).

You may want to combine them in lexicographical order, so that it doesn't matter the order in which they are provided. For the reasons provided above and less user errors by not being possible to provide them in an order it doesn't work.

**Option 3: Encrypt twice**

This option would be slower, although just doing two layers of encryption would not be a noticeable hit. You should perhaps be careful to do both things "at once" or with pipes, not using intermediate temporary files that might end up recovered. Although you would still have the same concern with the final decrypted item.

This solution would be subject to a [Meet-in-the-middle attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meet-in-the-middle_attack). I don't think this would actually be a realistic concern, since you would still need to break AES.

A new keyholder could be added by encrypting the existing ciphertext with the new key.

Same comment as above about setting an order would be applicable.

**Option 4: Split the key in two**

Just for completeness, I'm adding the trivial solution of, instead of giving 128 or 256 bit keys to each of them, directly providing half the key (64/128 bit keys) to each one. This means each key is half the size, with no benefit over the other solutions, so I wouldn't recommend it.